# Mutate and function using ifelse and &&

Tags: r, function, dplyr

i'm working with some dataset and i've create a function to manage the data:

```
library(dplyr)

testResults <- data.frame(
  X1 = c(431,432,433,434, 756),
  counter = c(4,5,6,7,5),
  Type = rep("ud", 5),
  Granularity = rep("package", 5),
  SeverityScore = c(5,6,2,4,10)
)



  level.fun <- function(Type, Granularity, SeverityScore){
   ifelse(as.character(Type) == "ud" && as.character(Granularity) == "package",
     ifelse(SeverityScore <= 8,1,
            ifelse(SeverityScore <= 19,2,
                   ifelse(SeverityScore <= 41,3,
                          ifelse(SeverityScore <= 116,4,
                                 ifelse(SeverityScore <= 608,5,0))))),0)


testResults <- mutate(testResults, SeverityScoreLevel = level.fun(Type, Granularity, SeverityScore))
```

which simply checks some values and return a result according to the conditions in the ifelse.
The problem is the all my return are 1s:

[image]

even if in the console, if i try `level.fun(testResults$Type[756], testResults$Granularity[756], testResults$SeverityScore[756])` the results is 2, which is correct. Same for line 761.

I thought even of using a for to slide all the row, but with a function that would be smarter.

Comment: Read about `cut()` function. Also, please provide example data, and update the question title, not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Change && (which returns a single T/F for the entire vector) to &:

```
library(dplyr)

testResults <- data.frame(
  X1 = c(431,432,433,434, 756),
  counter = c(4,5,6,7,5),
  Type = rep("ud", 5),
  Granularity = rep("package", 5),
  SeverityScore = c(5,6,2,4,10)
)

level.fun <- function(Type, Granularity, SeverityScore){
  ifelse(as.character(Type) == "ud" & as.character(Granularity) == "package",
         ifelse(SeverityScore <= 8,1,
                ifelse(SeverityScore <= 19,2,
                       ifelse(SeverityScore <= 41,3,
                              ifelse(SeverityScore <= 116,4,
                                     ifelse(SeverityScore <= 608,5,0))))),0)
}



mutate(testResults, SeverityScoreLevel = level.fun(Type, Granularity, SeverityScore)) 

##    X1 counter Type Granularity SeverityScore SeverityScoreLevel
## 1 431       4   ud     package             5                  1
## 2 432       5   ud     package             6                  1
## 3 433       6   ud     package             2                  1
## 4 434       7   ud     package             4                  1
## 5 756       5   ud     package            10                  2
```

HTH James

Comment: such a simple error...i'm quite the newbie with r, and i didn't expext that single & wuold work. I've lost all the morning on this, thanks again!

Comment: I went a couple of years before I understood the difference between & and &&.